# Trying to create a colored circle UIImage, but it always ends up square. Why?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, core-graphics, cgcontext

I have the following code. I want a blue circle created:

```
class func circleFromColor(_ color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)) -> UIImage? {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

    context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context.fill(rect)

    let radius: CGFloat = 8.0 * UIScreen.main.scale
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    maskPath.addClip()

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

However every single time it returns the image is a blue SQUARE. Not a circle, what gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newer way is to use UIGraphicsImageRenderer which gives you the correct point scale automatically.  Also a path can fill itself so there is no need for a clipping mask:

```
func circleFromColor(_ color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)) -> UIImage? {
  UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { context in
    color.setFill()
    UIBezierPath(ovalIn: .init(origin: .zero, size: size)).fill()
  }
}
```

Here is how you do it the old way:

```
func circleFromColor(_ color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)) -> UIImage? {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

    context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)

    let radius: CGFloat = 8.0 * UIScreen.main.scale
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    maskPath.addClip()
    maskPath.fill()

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Comment: Don't you need a "return" somewhere? Also that's awesome good stuff to know, but out of curiosity do you know what I'm doing wrong with my code sample?

Comment: Swift 5.1 slows you elide return for single expression functions.  Your code doesn't work because you are filling before you clip.

Comment: For context, fill and stroke draw to the buffer.  Mask does nothing except mask the NEXT drawing operation.  since you filled with a color already, your mask doesn't do anything because you don't draw anything after the mask has been enabled.

Comment: if I put the addClip() lines before the .fill() lines it still doesn't work

Comment: I fixed it above; I still don't recommend doing it that way though.

Comment: Thank you (and I won't just wanted to learn what I was doing wrong)