# Background Color to imageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview

[image]

I am trying to add a circle background to an image view. But I only see the image without background.

```swift
lazy var circle: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.image = UIImage(named: "iconsCancelThin")
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32)
    view.tintColor = KSColor.neutral700.getColor()
    view.backgroundColor = KSColor.neutral700.getColor()
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    return view
}()

guard let image = circle.image else { return }
self.cancelButton.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
```

Comment: Is the `iconsCancelThin` transparent? And you add the image, which is `UIImage(named: "iconsCancelThin")`, not the `view` which has a background color

Comment: so what is your suggestion?

Comment: You need to draw a new image. For drawing just the background, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313468/trying-to-create-a-colored-circle-uiimage-but-it-always-ends-up-square-why and to "combine" the two images, there should be available possbilities too. A little search should be enough